# CreateCondaEnvironmentException: The 'conda' command is not available inside your singularity container image

Tags: conda, snakemake, singularity-container

**Snakemake version**

```
conda: conda 4.8.3
snakemake: 5.17.0
singularity: 2.4.2-dist
```

**Describe the bug**

For some reasons, I can't use both singularity and conda together. I googled this error, but I can't find it anywhere.

**Logs**

```
Building DAG of jobs...
CreateCondaEnvironmentException:
The 'conda' command is not available inside your singularity container image. Snakemake mounts your conda installation into singularity. Sometimes, this can fail because of shell restrictions. It has been tested to work with docker://ubuntu, but it e.g. fails with docker://bash 
  File "/home/marina/anaconda3/envs/smk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 242, in create
  File "/home/marina/anaconda3/envs/smk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 363, in __new__
  File "/home/marina/anaconda3/envs/smk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 376, in __init__
  File "/home/marina/anaconda3/envs/smk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 394, in _check
```

**Minimal example**
My *Snakefile*:

```
import pandas as pd

SAMPLES_INFO = pd.DataFrame({'File': {0: 'SRX252719/SRR787552.chr15.fastq'},
                   'SAMPLE': {0: 'GSM1102782_CD14_H3K27ac'}})

rule all:
    input: expand("qc/fastqc/{sample}.html", sample=SAMPLES_INFO['SAMPLE'])
rule fast_qc:
    input:lambda wildcards: expand("reads/{file_name}", file_name=SAMPLES_INFO.loc[SAMPLES_INFO['SAMPLE'] == wildcards.sample, 'File'])
    output:
          html="qc/fastqc/{sample}.html",
          archive="qc/fastqc/{sample}_fastqc.zip"
    singularity: "docker://continuumio/miniconda3:4.5.11"
    conda:
         "envs/fast_qc.yaml"
    shell: "fastq --version && touch {output.html} && touch {output.archive}"
```

My _envs/fast_qc.yaml file_:

```
channels:
 - bioconda
dependencies:
 - fastqc=0.11.9
```

Execution:

```
snakemake --use-conda --use-singularity -j 1
```

Verbose output:

```
Singularity image location: /home/marina/master/scientific_python/test_smk/.snakemake/singularity/d7617773b315c3abcb29e0484085ed06.simg
 singularity exec --home /home/marina/master/scientific_python/test_smk  --bind /home/marina/anaconda3/envs/smk/lib/python3.7/site-packages:/mnt/snakemake /home/marina/master/scientific_python/test_smk/.snakemake/singularity/d7617773b315c3abcb29e0484085ed06.simg sh -c 'type conda'
Full Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marina/anaconda3/envs/smk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 390, in _check
    shell.check_output(self._get_cmd("type conda"), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/home/marina/anaconda3/envs/smk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/shell.py", line 45, in check_output
    cmd, shell=True, executable=cls.get_executable(), **kwargs
  File "/home/marina/anaconda3/envs/smk/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/home/marina/anaconda3/envs/smk/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 487, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command ' singularity exec --home /home/marina/master/scientific_python/test_smk  --bind /home/marina/anaconda3/envs/smk/lib/python3.7/site-packages:/mnt/snakemake /home/marina/master/scientific_python/test_smk/.snakemake/singularity/d7617773b315c3abcb29e0484085ed06.simg sh -c 'type conda'' returned non-zero exit status 255.
```

Comment: Not sure it this is an issue but why do you have two quotation marks for `singularity:`? You may want to use snakemake's `--verbose` flag, which will show the exact command that snakemake uses with singularity.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, I've removed extra quotes from my post. Also, I added the verbose output.

Comment: probably not related to your issue, but strongly recommend upgrading to the most recent 3.x version of singularity you can. 2.x is no longer supported and versions < 2.6.1 having notable security issues.

Comment: Have you tried [interacting with the singularity image](https://singularity.lbl.gov/quickstart#shell) to verify it does have `conda`? On quick check on my machine, it does have `conda` as expected.